# SwiftData access relationship property crash

Tags: swift-data

I just want to create a temporary Playlist. When I access songs of playlist, it crashed.

There are two model as below,

```
@Model
final class Playlist: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    var name: String
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Song.playlists)
    var songs: [Song]
    
    init(name: String, songs: [Song]) {
        self.name = name
        self.songs = songs
    }
}
```

```
@Model
final class Song: Identifiable {
    var name: String
    var artist: String
    var albumName: String
    
    var playlists: [Playlist] = []
    
    init(name: String, artist: String = "", albumName: String = "") {
        self.name = name
        self.artist = artist
        self.albumName = albumName
    }
}
```

The code will crash and report `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

```
let p = Playlist(name: "xxxx", songs: [Song(name: "PPPPP")])
print("----------> \(p.songs)")
```

Is this problem a bug of the SwiftData framework or something else?

Comment: Have you updated to beta 7 for both Xcode and iOS?

Comment: @HangarRash I just updated and it still crashes

Comment: are you sure `SMSong` is the correct name for your `@Model final class ...`, and not `Song`.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine The `SMSong` was a clerical error and I have corrected the description.